# How to disable double clicks or timeout clicks with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, click, double-click

I have an anchor which is using jQuery .click event to start a few functions.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('a.slide_circ').click(function(){ 
        do_all_functions();
        return false; 
    });
});
```

This is the code in short..
Its working as it needs to, every click on anchor class slide_circ start do_all_functions.

But I have a problem there. If user make double clicks they run 2 times or more the functions...
And the how idea go to hell.

I think that I need to disable the double click some way or to set timeout on my function so its not running each time. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: `And the how idea go to hell.` What?

Comment: So you want the click handler to only work once, ever? Or what? Tried setting a variable?

Comment: No I want it to works as many times as there are clicks.
But if user clicks fast 2-3-4 times, to block those clicks.
Normal click interval is 500ms , so if user has clicked 2 times or more in 500ms, the script should run just 1 time my function, not 2-3-4..

Comment: That's not what your question says. In it, you appear to suggest that you _don't_ want two function invocations when your user clicks twice. _[edit: right, ok. That's clearer then.]_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to assign the state to the element. Then, use `setTimeout` to reset the state:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.slide_circ').click(function() { 
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if ($this.data('activated')) return false;  // Pending, return

        $this.data('activated', true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.data('activated', false)
        }, 500); // Freeze for 500ms

        do_all_functions();
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: This works perfect :) 
I tried to put the same Timeout but I did one mistake..
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do it, but one way is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    var do_all_functions_running = false; 
    jQuery('a.slide_circ').click(function(){
        if (!do_all_functions_running) { 
            do_all_functions_running = true;
            do_all_functions();
            do_all_functions_running = false;
        }
        return false;   
    });  
});
```

Not perfect, but it'll work.

Comment: this won't work, you're setting the click event when you use .click(), not executing the function.

Comment: This method is equivalent to `.unbind('click')`, because the function will now only run once, and never again.

Comment: Re-reading the question (or rather the comments), he wants it to run for as many times as it is clicked. So ignore my attempt...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the last date of the run, and cancel if it was less than half a second ago:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.slide_circ').each(function() {
        var lastRun = null;

        $(this).click(function() {
            if(lastRun && new Date() - lastRun < 500) {
                // Less than 500ms; ignore.
                return false;
            }

            // Set the last run:
            lastRun = new Date().getTime();

            // Continue:
            do_all_functions();
            return false; 
        });
    });
});
```

It has the advantage of being a little more efficient.

Comment: It doesn't work with more than one `a.slide_circ` element. They'll conflict with each other.